# SQL Comparing Two Columns and Overwriting values to keep track of a maximum

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I'm pretty new to SQL and this feels like a very simple question, yet I can't come up with my own solution.

I have a table T -- to simplify it there are two columns: Vals and Max. Vals and Max hold floats, and Max keeps track of the highest value that Vals has been at, because I constantly update the Vals column. So:

Vals.....Max

4..........3

5..........2

8..........9

2..........5

9..........4

Would become

Vals.....Max

4..........4

5..........5

8..........9

2..........5

9..........9

Comment: You could implement the logic within a trigger so that each time the `Vals` column is updated, the `Max` column is also checked and updated as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
update mytable set [max]=[vals] where [vals]>[max]
```

Note that max is a reserved word, so you may want to pick another name to keep things simple.